# OpenVPN & China's Great Firewall

Tags: vpn, firewalls, openvpn

The company I work for has an OpenVPN server so we can access its intranet from home.

The problem is that I'm going to move to China and I'll need to connect from there, but I've heard connections with OpenVPN protocol are blocked by the Great Firewall (for example, they are identified by its distinctive handshake and then the server IP gets blocked).

Given that I have no control over my company's OpenVPN server, how could I connect to it and bypass the firewall?

This is what I've thought of so far:

- Set up a server outside of China (VPS, Raspberry Pi at a friend's house, etc)
- Connect to the server from China using some tunnel proxy like Shadowsocks or v2ray, which should be fine, in theory
- Configure an OpenVPN client in the server and somehow forward all the traffic to it.

Does it even make sense? Can you think of a better option?

Comment: Have you looked up your options? https://gfw.report/talks/imc20/en/#:~:text=In%20summary%2C%20the%20Great%20Firewall,or%20have%20certain%20payload%20lengths. Have you discussed this with your company?

Answer (score 1):

**This should be discussed with your company IT**

If you are going to work in China, I assume your company is ok with that, or they may even be the ones *moving* you to China.

There may already be other employees of your company based in China, in which case, there will be some process for them to access the company resources. Or, if you are the first one, it is something that should be treated as its own project.

If I were the security team of your company, an unexpected login attempt from China would be a red flag. Somewhat unhappy when it is discovered later that this move had been planned for months and nobody cared to notify us. And pretty angry when a computer suddenly "has to be made to work" behind GFO.

Whereas properly planning would allow preparing the ways to connect beforehand, analysing the available options, and preparing the computer while it's still within reach.